# VFS sqlite in Java

Tags: java, sqlite, vfs

We have our own VFS implementation for sqlite, and I was wondering if there is a way to use a non default VFS when opening a JDBC SQLITE adapter?

I could not find any documentation about it. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs_find.html

Comment: @leeor - this requires a JNI if I'm not mistaken. I was talking about sqlite JDBC API - if there is any way to configure it to use a specific VFS (without JNI). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC is a standardized interface, so it has no mechanism for database-specific functions such as SQLite's VFS.